# I am taking data from an api, but i get the error message "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Tags: python-3.x

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
link = requests.get('https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar')
data = link.text
dictionary = json.loads(data)
print(str(dictionary['products']['BROWN_MUSHROOM']['sell_summary']['sellPrice']))
```

The api is on api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar/

Comment: The data in `dictionary['products']['BROWN_MUSHROOM']['sell_summary']` is actually a list of dictionaries, none of which contain `'sellPrice'`, try `print(str(dictionary['products']['BROWN_MUSHROOM']['quick_status']['sellPrice']))`

Comment: Give us how your `dictionary` looks like.

Comment: The dictionary is on api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar/ but someone already solved my promlem, thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Sell summary returns a list of the top sell offers, not an average sell price. So, you were looking in the wrong place, which is why it gave you an error. Maybe you were looking for this instead?

```py
>>> dictionary['products']['BROWN_MUSHROOM']['quick_status']['sellPrice']
18.3
```

Hope this helps and you haven't given up.

Answer (score -1):

Without an example of the API response I can just say that the error:

```
"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"
```

Means that you are trying to get a value from a `list` using `key` like it's a dictionary. Somewhere in your `dictionary` value you have a list of values.